# Why does test case using Django's assertInHTML() method fail?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Given the following Django test case, why does it fail?  And just as important, what can I do to test for the presence of the HTML element `<form class="bc-form" id="update_template" action="" method="get" novalidate>`?

```
from django.test import TestCase
class Test_assertInHTML(TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        needle = '<form class="bc-form" id="update_template" action="" method="get" novalidate>'
        haystack = '''<html>
                <form class="bc-form" id="update_template" action="" method="get" novalidate>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><th>Template Name </th><td><select name="name" id="id_name"></select></td></tr>
                            <tr><th>Format </th><td><select name="format" id="id_format">
                                <option value="E">Email</option>
                                <option value="S">SMS</option>
                                </select>
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr><th>The message </th><td><textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" required id="id_message"></textarea></td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </html>'''
        self.assertInHTML(needle, haystack, count=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your needle is an incomplete HTML fragment, which is not valid HTML.

The [documentation for `assertInHTML`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertInHTML) states that both arguments (needle and haystack) must be valid HTML. The parser first validates the HTML and discards anything that is invalid - hence your test fails.

If you just want to test that the opening form tag is rendered, then you will need to do simple string comparison instead of using `assertInHTML`.